# Question about wavelength of EM wave in dielectric

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, wavelength, dielectric

Many websites (http://maxwells-equations.com/materials/permittivity.php) lists out the following formula as to how you can compute the wavelength of an EM wave in a dielectric

$$\lambda_d = \lambda_o/\sqrt\epsilon_r$$

This doesn't sit well with me.

I wonder where did $\mu_r$ the magnetic permeability went? Why don't we have 
$$\lambda_d = \lambda_o/\sqrt{\mu_r\epsilon_r}$$
instead?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're perfectly correct. Referring to Classical Electrodynamics by Jackson, we see that the index of refraction $n$ is given by:

$$n=\sqrt{\frac{\mu}{\mu_{0}}\frac{\epsilon}{\epsilon_{0}}} = \sqrt{\mu_{r}\epsilon_{r}}.$$ But Jackson notes that for most optical frequencies (and non-meta-material media), $\frac{\mu}{\mu_{0}}=\mu_{r}\approx 1$, which is why we often simplify this to $n=\sqrt{\epsilon_{r}}$. Your wavelength equation follows from there.

Comment: Can you think of a media where $\mu_r$ is not one? I'll treat that case as the exception from now on. Thank you

Comment: Not off the top of my head. I know that there is a lot of research going on into such meta-materials (negative refractive indices, perfect lenses, invisibility cloaks), but most common materials which have $\mu_{r}\neq 1$ (like ferromagnetic materials) are opaque at optical frequencies.